# Wide table problem when generating PDF

Tags: tables, conversion, r

I have a LaTeX wide table generated from a data frame in R using `xtable`, but when the PDF is created not all the data is shown, just a part of it, and the other part is hidden on the right of the PDF. How this can be solved?

```
cat("\\documentclass{article}\n\begin{document}\n", file=txt)
 print(xtable(table), include.rownames=TRUE, floating=FALSE, file=txt, append=TRUE)   
  cat("\\end{document}\n", file=txt, append=TRUE)
```

where should i place the scalebox thing ??

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest either to rotate the Table, using the [lscape](http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/help/Catalogue/entries/lscape.html) package, or to resize your table (easier, IMHO) with `\scalebox` from the [graphics](http://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CTAN/help/Catalogue/entries/graphics.html) package. I often use the latter for "not too large" tables (say, 10 rows by 5 to 7 columns with custom headings), that won't fit in a rotated page. It has to be done from within your `tex` file.

Here is a toy example:

- In R:

  ```
  x <- replicate(2, sample(LETTERS[1:10], 100, rep=T))
  tab <- table(x[,1], x[,2])
  library(xtable)
  print(xtable(tab, digits=0), file="tab.tex", floating=FALSE)
  ```

Here we ask to write the resulting table in a file (you may have to change the full path to reflect your working tex directory), `tab.tex`. This way, you don't have to edit your Latex file too much.

- In Latex:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{graphics}

  \begin{document}
  \scalebox{0.9}{\input{tab}}
  \end{document}
  ```

The scaling factor used here, 0.9, means 90% of text width. See the on-line help for further details. You can then compile the resulting file with `pdflatex`.

There's a subtlety here: I didn't ask to get a floating table (see `floating=FALSE` when calling `xtable()`), bacause we can't use `\scalebox` around a float. Should you want to add caption, label, etc., you just need to replace the above command with

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\input{tab}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Finally, the landscape solution is easily obtained as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\input{tab}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Here, it will work with or without asking for a floating object when calling `xtable()` in R.

---

**Edit:**

With the syntax you provided in your updated question, here's is how it should read:

```
cat("\\documentclass{article}\n\\usepackage{graphics}\n\\begin{document}\n", file="1.tex")
cat("\\scalebox{0.7}{", file="1.tex", append=TRUE)
print(xtable(tab), include.rownames=TRUE, floating=FALSE, file="1.tex", append=TRUE) 
cat("}", file="1.tex", append=TRUE)  
cat("\\end{document}\n", file="1.tex", append=TRUE)
```

Here, `tab` refers to the two-by-two table from my example, replace it by `table` if you named it like this (which is not a good idea because this is the name of an R function). The table is already aligned on the left margin. So, if you want to change that, a quick and dirty fix is to ask for right to left shift (I'm pretty sure TeXnicians know of a better way to do that):

```
cat("\\scalebox{0.7}{\\hskip-50pt", file="1.tex", append=TRUE)
```

Comment: @chl : thanks for toy reply , but i'm new to latex , how can i do this inside R??(e.g resize the table) , and i can also abbreviate column names. but how should i resize it first in xtable() ?? thanks

Comment: @weblover I added some example of use. I hope it is clear now. If you're using Sweave, it's a little bit different, but not so much.

Comment: @chl : thank you for your help , but the 2nd way in Latex , i did not now how to include it in my code , i will post my code in the question and maybe you can give me further help .and is there any way to align the table more to the left inside the PDF ??

Comment: @weblover I corrected and updated your code in my response. HTH

Comment: @chl : thank you alot , that's worked , but the table still nedd to be shifted to the left , because it still some missing variables ,

Answer (score 1):

```
cat("\\documentclass{article}\n\\usepackage{graphics}\n\\begin{document}\n", file="1.tex")
cat("\\scalebox{0.7}{", file="1.tex", append=TRUE)
print(xtable(tab), include.rownames=TRUE, floating=FALSE, file="1.tex", append=TRUE) 
cat("}", file="1.tex", append=TRUE)  
cat("\\end{document}\n", file="1.tex", append=TRUE)
```